# How to change list values based on value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I apologise if the title is misleading and if this question has already been asked but I personally couldn't find it anywhere.

In my entire project, X is your intelligence and the list is your grades (list[0] being A**, list[1] being A* etc.). So the higher the intelligence, the higher chance you'll have of getting A** and A*'s

I have a script that generates a list of random length with random integers that sum to a specified number.

```
from random import randint as ri

x = 72

def seq(n): #Returns list of random length of random ints that add to n

    a = []

    def f(n):
        m = ri(1, n)
        if n > m:
            a.append(str(m))
            return f(n - m)
        else:
            a.append(str(n))
            return n

    f(n)
    return a #Will return ["4", "2", "3", "1"] for example
```

What I want is that, the higher `x` is, the more the first items will increase and the more the last items will decrease.

For example, say:

```
x = 26

#I want ["4", "2", "3", "1"] to turn into something like ["4", "3", "2", "1"]
```

But if:

```
x = 80

#I want ["4", "2", "3", "1"] to turn into something like ["6", "4", "2", “0”]
```

Sorry if my wording is confusing, I really struggled putting this problem into words (It happens to all of us doesn't it `;)` )

Comment: why don't you sort your list at the end?

Comment: What is x supposed to represent, how does the desired result scales with regard to x?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon In my entire project, X is our intelligence and the list is your grades (list[0] being A**, list[1] being A* etc.). So the higher the intelligence, the higher chance you'll have of getting A** and A*'s

Comment: A better description of what you want to do is needed—the result of producing one might even make the code  that implements it obvious. Also, don't put the description down here in a comment, instead [edit] your question so no one misses it.

Comment: @martineau I’ve updated the post, thanks

Comment: What is the correspondence between grades like "A*" and "A**" and the numeric values being put in the list being created? What are all the possible grades? Also, in your code appears that `n` is some undefined global variable, correct?

Comment: I think you need a [skewed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) probability distribution, not a uniform one (that's what `random.randint` provides). With a skewed distribution, after twiddling some of its parameters, smarter students will _randomly_ tend to get better marks, and vice versa.

Comment: @VersionOmega Why do you want the smallest result to decrease if intelligence increases? And why did the length of the list change with x=80?

Comment: @Melançon should’ve made it clearer; the smallest result won’t change, the last items in the list will change. And the length of the list changed because the A**’s increased, A*’s increased but the student got no A’s or B’s. Hope that made sense

Comment: @ForceBru how would I go about that? I’ve found results with SciPy but that doesn’t seem what I’m looking for

Comment: @martineau the grades are A**, A*, A, B, C, D and F. The numbers in the list are the quantity of grades that student achieves. For example, if the list was “4”, “2”, “3”, he student would have 4x A**’s, 2x A*’s and 3x A’s. The code posted is a snippet of code from my project where n is just a place holder variable.

Comment: OK, that info helps and I have an idea. However I can't work on this any further right now—so I'll just describe it. The idea is to use the intelligence `x` factor to skew a distribution of grades produced towards the higher or lower range of values by different degrees. A library that can produce skewed distributions would be useful.

Comment: [`scipy.stats.skewnorm()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skewnorm.html) looks promising.